# Access disk D after installing Ubuntu on disk C

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, windows

I have a Windows HP laptop that has two separate disks. Disk C (contains windows + 230 GB) and Disk D (1 TB).

I decided to switch to Ubuntu and completely remove Windows because friends told me dual booting both OS will significantly slow my laptop. I followed all the steps recommended on ubuntu's website to download the OS by booting it to a USB.

When the installer asked me where did I want to install Ubuntu, I chose at first disk D with the erase everything option. I thought this would remove Windows. What happened is that Windows stayed on the C and Ubuntu used the D. I had a dual boot system. I then removed the dual Ubuntu and allocated the 1 TB space back to Windows. I reinstalled Ubuntu, but this time I chose disk C that contains Windows to remove everything and replace it with Ubuntu. This seems to have successfully removed Windows from my laptop.

The problem that I am facing however, is that I am not able to find the Disk D (with 1 TB of empty space) to use it with Ubuntu. When I open the terminal and type `df -h` It shows me that I have around 80 GB free only.

How can I access the other drive?

Comment: Dual booting would not affect laptop performance.  What is the justification for this claim?  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Please note the C & D are labels (names) only and not your actual drives.  The idea of using letter to represent floppy drives was introduced long ago, and continues in windows (A & B were floppies, C the first hard drive). If you look in your BIOS/uEFI setup you'll see some drive details which would suit you better than labels/names that don't exist except in windows. You have provided no details as to your second drive, but format it & add it to the system file-system-table (`/etc/fstab` do it mounts wherever you like. Other ways exist as well

Answer (score 0):

You friends were wrong when they said dual booting would slow your laptop. Dual booting means using Windows or Linux but not both at the same time.

What you call your D drive is still there. If you open a terminal (Ctrl Alt T or find it in activities) and type lsblk you will get a list of the drives and partitions on your laptop. What is the D drive under Windows is probably sdb1.

If you use the disks application you should also be able to see the 1TB disk. To access it with the files app you need to mount it first. You can mount it with the disks app or with a terminal command. To mount it every time you log on you need to add an entry to your /etc/fstab file. I suggest you research how to do that there are plenty of articles online that tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

As @PonJar points out it is possible to add a drive to your Ubuntu install after the fact.  It may be easier for a relative novice, and someone that hasn't invested much time yet in customizing their Ubuntu install, is to start over with the install and use the custom partitioning option from the installer to add the drive.

Customizing your partitioning from the default carries some hazards and difficulties as one should know enough about what partitions are needed, some minimal knowledge on what each partition does, and perhaps a few other helpful details.  I recommend this as an alternative to trying to add the drive after the fact as the installer should provide some sanity checks and create the file system table for you.  This may be less of a hazard to breaking anything in the system and leave your computer unstable or unbootable.

As it's been a while since I've done this myself I can't give much for guidance on how to do this.  I will say though that at a minimum you will need a swap and root partition.  After that there are many options on how to spread the partitions over two disks.  One common scheme is to have a separate swap drive from the drive containing the root partition, this should improve performance by keeping memory swap access separate from file I/O.  This might not apply all that much with solid state drives where there is no head movement to slow down access to widely spread portions of the disk.  Another common scheme is to have a home drive separate from the root drive.  By keeping the home partition on a separate drive there can be ample room for one's documents and not be concerned about documents crowding out system files.

I'll end with pointing out that dual booting a computer should not affect the performance of a computer.  The drive with the alternate OS is effectively invisible to the one booted at the time.  If dual booting is attractive to you then feel free to reinstall Windows.  I suggest doing some research on the best partitioning scheme for your intended uses and have a plan on what goes where before installing Windows.  Windows doesn't "play nice" with other operating systems so you should install it first and leave room for your Ubuntu install when partitioning the drives.  An option this leaves for you is you can split one drive for Windows and Linux swap, then have the other drive for Linux root.  Maybe you could decide to have a shared data drive for each OS so that Windows and Linux both have access to this drive but leave the system files "invisible" to the other so that you do not accidentally mangle the boot partitions.

What it comes down to is that there is no "best" way to handle two drives on an Ubuntu install.  This gets even more complex if you want to dual boot with Windows.  You'll have to decide what works best for you and spending some time to plan this out can save you some headaches later.